# "chrome" tag automatically converts to "google-chrome"

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, sponsored-tags

I had a question about firefox chrome earlier, and so I added the tag `chrome` to it  When I submitted the question, it had turned `chrome` into `google-chrome` with a little google chrome icon beside it.  Is that really necessary?

Comment: [browser-chrome] is more specific and probably more helpful in this case.

Comment: That's not a bug, that's a revenue stream! :P

Comment: @al-everett thanks, you're right.  Still, it seems biased to associate the word chrome with google chrome; how was I to know that chrome would refer to the google type?  And how was I to think of [browser-chrome] as the proper tag?  It could have been [firefox-chrome], [mozilla-chrome], [xul-chrome], etc.

Answer (score 9):

Yes - [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome) is a [synonym for](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-chrome/synonyms) [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome). It's entirely deliberate, to give a *canonical* tag name, making it easier to search etc.

Comment: And the little icon indicates a sponsored tag, whose usability is orthogonal to tag synonyms.